# Applying a Regex to a Substring Without using String Slice

Tags: python, regex

I want to search for a regex match in a larger string **from a certain position onwards**, and **without using string slices**.

My background is that I want to search through a string iteratively for matches of various regex's. A natural solution in Python would be keeping track of the current position within the string and using e.g.

```
re.match(regex, largeString[pos:])
```

in a loop. But for really large strings (~ 1MB) string slicing as in `largeString[pos:]` becomes expensive. I'm looking for a way to get around that.

Side note: Funnily, in a niche of the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching), it talks about an optional `pos` parameter to the match function (which would be exactly what I want), which is not to be found with the functions themselves :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variants with pos and endpos parameters only exist as members of regular expression objects. Try this:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("match here")
input = "don't match here, but do match here"
start = input.find(",")
print pattern.search(input, start).span()
```

... outputs `(25, 35)`

Comment: This is crazy! The ``pos`` param is actually there, but only with the object methods! I must have been blind ... Thanks a lot, also to the other guys.

Answer (score 4):

The `pos` keyword is only available in the method versions. For example,

```
re.match("e+", "eee3", pos=1)
```

is invalid, but

```
pattern = re.compile("e+")
pattern.match("eee3", pos=1)
```

works.

Comment: ... and I was so sure that the only difference between the module function and the object method was the regex parameter (and maybe the flags) :-/ . Blame me.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> m=re.compile ("(o+)")
>>> m.match("oooo").span()
(0, 4)
>>> m.match("oooo",2).span()
(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use positive lookbehinds, like so:

```python
import re

test_string = "abcabdabe"

position=3
a = re.search("(?<=.{" + str(position) + "})ab[a-z]",test_string)

print a.group(0)
```

yields:

```
abd
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but for long input strings, if I'm searching towards the end of that string, this would make a verrryyyy long look-behind :). But I'll keep it for later.